# Machine learning: How to fix part of the weight matrix?

Tags: machine-learning

Consider a linear layer with 2*2 weights

```
linear = LinearLayer[2, "Input" -> 2];

net = NetInitialize[linear];
```

After the initialization, the four elements of the weight matrix W can be read

```
W = NetExtract[net, "Weights"]
(* {{0.551202, -1.10384}, {-0.659195, -1.12961}} *)

data = {{1, 1} -> {2, 3}, {2, 2} -> {4, 5.9}, {3, 3} -> {6, 9.1}, {4, 
     4} -> {8, 12.1}};

trainednet = NetTrain[net, data];

trainednet[{7, 7}]
(* {14., 21.25} *)
```

After training, the initial four weights W have been changed

```
NetExtract[trainednet, "Weights"]
(* {{1.82752, 0.17248}, {1.76021, 1.28979}} *)
```

Question: Is it possible to fix three of the weights (e.g., `W[[1,1]]=1,W[[1,2]]=1,W[[2,1]]=1` ) so that only one weight (`W[[2,2]]`) can be changed during the training?

Comment: It will help if you provide additional input. May be a MWE, references, etc....

Comment: Thank Jason and Nasser.  I have re-edited the question.

Comment: I would restate the question as an ability to specify a hook for optimization step, in order to mask the gradient however I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
net = NetGraph[
   {
    ConstantArrayLayer[{3}, "Array" -> {1, 1, 1}],
    ConstantArrayLayer[{1}],
    CatenateLayer[],
    ReshapeLayer[{2, 2}],
    DotLayer[],
    2,
    SoftmaxLayer[]
    },
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> 5, {1, 2} -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
    },
   "Input" -> 2,
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
NetExtract[net, {1, "Array"}]
```

> {1., 1., 1.}

```
NetExtract[net, {2, "Array"}]
```

> {0.}

```
netT = NetTrain[
  net,
  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}] -> RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100],
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {1 -> 0, _ -> 1},
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 10
  ]
```

[image]

```
NetExtract[netT, {1, "Array"}]
```

> {1., 1., 1.}

```
NetExtract[netT, {2, "Array"}]
```

> {-0.0881761}

Comment: It really is what I want. Thank you so much.